# Is 'full-grown' only about physical growth?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, connotations

Is 'full-grown' only about physical growth? Does it have the connotation of mental growth? Say, does saying someone is full-grown imply that he/she is mentally mature by any means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a 19-year-old "full-grown", so it does not imply full mental maturity.

That said, calling someone "full-grown" can mean you expect them to have *a certain level of mental maturity*, that's to say, mental maturity typical of people who are past their teenage years. By 19 years old, for instance, we expect people to be able to share things and consider the feelings of others, which we do not expect of 2-year-olds.